# Is there a way to calculate how long a dot graph will take in graphviz?

Tags: graphviz, dot

Is there any way to calculate how long a dot graph will likely take to render?

I am currently running with 25,000 nodes and 42,000 edges. It's taking some hours and I'd like to know if to give up or get an estimated time when it completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: nope.
Longer answer:  There are things you can do to better understand what dot is doing and make it run faster.

- Adding `-v4` (https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/command.html#-v) to the command line will (help) show progress (not well documented) (4 is arbitrary)
- There are 5 or more attributes that you can use to improve performance (**mclimit, nslimit, nslimit1, remincross** and **searchsize**) (again, not well documented)  As a guess, try setting nslimit and nslimit1 both to 2.

Here are some links to more performance info:

- (Linux:) Logging w/ timestamp: https://forum.graphviz.org/t/how-to-timestamp-dot-fdp-neato-twopi-circo-v-output/654
- https://forum.graphviz.org/t/where-does-generating-the-graph-take-most-of-the-time/668/3
- https://forum.graphviz.org/t/dot-command-seems-to-never-end/958/4
- You might be having a "footprint" problem with all those nodes (Too many square inches of node space)  Minimally, set output format to **svg**.
- Some "innocent" attributes can also be killers, like `splines=ortho` (https://forum.graphviz.org/t/creating-a-dot-graph-with-thousands-of-nodes/1092)
- (future) https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/2135

25,000 nodes is a fair number of nodes, but 42,000 edges is not that many edges/node
With that many nodes, you might also try some of the other Graphviz engines (neato, fdp, circo, twopi)  Often, one or more will run much faster.